# Is defining something the same as listing the properties of it?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics

In mathematics, we often define things through assuming certain basic things exist and then listing properties about them to restrict how they behave ( eg ZFC).

I once read a euphemistic description of this definition:

"If it quacks like a duck, behaves like a duck , then it is a duck... That's the pattern of how ZFC works"

I'm trying to think if there is any real critique inside this euphemism at all. Is there really anything wrong( or say unsatisfying) with defining things through it's properties?

Comment: Definition: words that describe 1. characteristics of a thing 2. what it does 3. how to identify it 4. other things it is related to - Does that work as a definition? Maybe we can improve on it. 5. how it can be modified / improved...

Comment: "Definition" is a highly ambiguous word, it has a host of different meanings, see [SEP, Definitions](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/definitions). So no, there are ways of defining aside from listing properties. But I am not sure the quote even alludes to this way of defining as such. It might refer to extensionality, identifying concepts with their extensions (ignoring how they are presented), and/or to limited supply of expressible properties, which leads to informally distinct things being "identified" (like geometric vectors with strings of numbers), etc.

Comment: Axiomatc theories "define" things indirectly: the "universe" of *sets* is made of all and only those objects that satisfy the axioms of the theory.

Comment: Thus, following @ScottRowe's comment above, the axioms of set theory (all together) 1) describe the characteristics of sets, 2) what they do (mathematically) 3) how to identify them.

Comment: *God and the Devil were strolling one day when suddenly God bent down and picked up a shining, jewel-like thing and held it aloft, saying,* "Now this, this is **Truth**." *The Devil snatched it away and exclaimed,* "Here, I'll organize that for you!"

Comment: "Duck Typing" became popular in Object Oriented Programming Systems (oops), I don't know who said it originally. The idea was to get a handle on blossoming ontologies (similar to Crash Blossoms) that were getting rapidly out of hand. Or something.

Comment: You might like Kunen's chapter on Definining Definability in his tectbook "An Introduction To Independence Proofs"

Comment: We can, essentially, define the set of natural numbers N using only 5 of its countless properties. See Peano's Axioms at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PeanosAxioms.html In theory anyway, I understand that we can derive all known properties of N from those axioms using the axioms of set theory and the rules of logical inference.